# Trying to add data from parse to an NSMutableArray in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsstring, nsmutablearray

So, I am able to successfully perform a query of my parse database. This query matches the logged in user with all objects that have the logged in user in the key user. The object I'm querying has keys "email" "firstName" "lastName" "friendUserName" and "phoneNumber"

I would like to be able to store all the phone numbers into a mutable array named phoneNumbers. The code I am trying to use to do this is.

```
int i=0;

            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                NSLog(@"%@", objects[i]);


                phonenumber = object[@"phoneNumber"];
                NSLog(@"%@", phonenumber);



               [phoneNumbers[i] addObject:phonenumber];

                NSLog(@"%@", phoneNumbers[i]);
                i=i+1;
            }
```

When I run this code the output for the code NSLog(@"%@", phoneNumbers[i]);
comes out a null both times. All other outputs are as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];

for (PFObject *object in objects) {
    NSLog(@"%@", object);

    // Assuming your phone numbers are stored as strings - use a different data type if necessary
    NSString *phoneNumber = object[@"phoneNumber"];
    NSLog(@"%@", phoneNumber);

    [phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
}

NSLog(@"%@", phoneNumbers);
```

If you're just adding items to the end of a mutable array, you don't need to worry about the index of the items.

The place you were going wrong was when trying to add the object to your array. You were doing this:

```
[phoneNumbers[i] addObject:phonenumber];
```

Which is actually saying "fetch the object at index `i` in the `phoneNumbers` array, and tell it to add the phone number object". However, presumably your array is empty or not initialised, which means `addObject` will be sent to a nil object and so not have any effect. Instead, you simply need to tell the `phoneNumbers` array itself to add the object.

Comment: AHH it worked :) ! Is there a reason you could share why mine didn't?

Comment: No, Problem! I tried to accept it initially, but it made me wait a few minutes first.